# jQuery Validation - validate email using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I have an invitation form that should only accept emails handled by GMail. I'm trying to plug in asynchronous validation, but not sure what should be returned from the server and what Javascript handlers to use.

1. I would like to display "Not a GMail address" next to email input field if someone types a Yahoo email
2. I would like to receive "Not a GMail address" message from the backend.

My attempt (not very good):

```
$('#invite').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form, e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: {
                email: $(form).find('#email').val()
            },
            success: function() {debugger;},
            error: function() {alert('failed');}
        });

        return false;
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        debugger;
    },
    rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true,
          remote: {
            url: "/invite.php",
            type: "post",
            async: true,
            data: submittedEmail
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be on the backend? This seems like a great case to validate on the client first, checking the email input value *before* sending back to the server, so you can save your user's an HTTP request.

Comment: The reason is that any domain can be handled by GMail Google Business Apps. I need to run MX check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved.

Javascript code:

```
$('#invite').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: '/admin/isgmail/',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    email: function() {
                        return $('#email').val();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: "GMail email is required."
    },
    onkeyup: false
});
```

`invite.php` should return string **"true"** if validation is successful, string **"false"** if there was an error OR JSON-encoded string describing the error: `echo json_encode('This is not a Google account');`.

Comment: Right. Only documentation is very hard to use.