# JQuery Validation - Check if email exists if it's already valid

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

i'm using jquery validation to validate forms, i'm using addMethod to check if the email already exists or not, but can i check only if email is valid from the original validation rule, cuz using current implementation wastes processing on non valid emails from the start ?

```
   $.validator.addMethod("EmailValidator", function(value, element) {
    return value=="x@gmail.com"; ///changing this to ajax call
}, "Email is already registered");

        $(".edit-user-form").validate({
        rules:{
            email:{
                EmailValidator:true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can use the `remote` validation option to validate a property via an AJAX request. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23312240/519413

Comment: i know how to implement ajax call, but will this call be called only and only if the email valid ie(x@y.z) ? also can i make just an indicator so the user can submit with the email already existing ?